# Installing PHP Extensions on RedHat

Tags: php, linux, redhat

I've installed PHP via Yum on RedHat (minimal install; no GUI), but in order for me to install an application on the system I need to install [PHP Mcrypt extension](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php). How does this work? Should I remove PHP via Yum and install from source and use the parameters in the above link (**--with-mcrypt[=DIR]**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a separate package. In packaged Linux they break the separate compiled extensions into their own library and then include those. Try this

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

I should also note that [mcrypt may be deprecated in the future](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

Comment: Doing that I get the following message: `No package php-mcrypt available.` I'm running using `sudo`

Comment: @user721015 Hmm, are you using the base repository or another repository? If you've not tried, consider [using the Remi repo](http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en) which should have that for you

Comment: Odd, it's called `php-mcrypt` on both Fedora and CentOS. Try `yum search mcrypt` to list all the available mcrypt-related packages. Your spelling might vary slightly. Maybe it's `php5-mcrypt` on RedHat?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yeah, the Debian flavors do the `php5` thing but it never worked that well under yum when trying to resolve dependencies because RHEL flavors would bind to the minor version with CentOS5 having PHP 5.1 so they'd package differently (i.e. `php54`, `php55` etc) and that would tend to lock people into that minor version (assuming everything that required php packages would use these oddly named packages). Most repos just have `php` for that reason (use the repo for the version you want). I'm curious how the Debian flavors will handle `php7`